Remove duplicate from nested json array using jolt spec
please provide the jolt spec to get the desired output json
below provided jolt spec is needs to updated to remove the dupicate inside the subitems array
the input JSON :
[
  {
    "itemid": "1",
    "itemName": "coco",
    "itemType": "brg",
    "subitemId": "444",
    "subitemName": "INDICATIVE",
    "Status": "N"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "1",
    "itemName": "coco",
    "itemType": "brg",
    "subitemId": "333",
    "subitemName": "BRGS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "1",
    "itemName": "coco",
    "itemType": "brg",
    "subitemId": "444",
    "subitemName": "INDICATIVE",
    "Status": "N"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "1",
    "itemName": "coco",
    "itemType": "brg",
    "subitemId": "333",
    "subitemName": "BRGS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "2",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "456",
    "subitemName": "NMPS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "2",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "4568",
    "subitemName": "NMPSI",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "2",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "456",
    "subitemName": "NMPS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "2",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "4568",
    "subitemName": "NMPSI",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "3",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "789",
    "subitemName": "NMPS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "3",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "789",
    "subitemName": "NMPS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "3",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "789",
    "subitemName": "NMPS",
    "Status": "P"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "3",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "873",
    "subitemName": "NMSI",
    "Status": "N"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "3",
    "itemName": "limk",
    "itemType": "cmds",
    "subitemId": "873",
    "subitemName": "NMSI",
    "Status": "N"
  }
]

Expected output JSON :
[
  {
    "work_item": {
      "itemid": "1",
      "itemName": "coco",
      "itemType": "brg",
      "wf_instance": {
        "subitems": [
          {
            "currentsubitemId": "444",
            "currentsubitemName": "INDICATIVE",
            "CurrentStatus": "NotPresent"
          },
          {
            "currentsubitemId": "333",
            "currentsubitemName": "BRGS",
            "CurrentStatus": "Present"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "work_item": {
      "itemid": "2",
      "itemName": "limk",
      "itemType": "cmds",
      "wf_instance": {
        "subitems": [
          {
            "currentsubitemId": "456",
            "currentsubitemName": "NMPS",
            "CurrentStatus": "Present"
          },
          {
            "currentsubitemId": "4568",
            "currentsubitemName": "NMPSI",
            "CurrentStatus": "Present"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "work_item": {
      "itemid": "3",
      "itemName": "limk",
      "itemType": "cmds",
      "wf_instance": {
        "subitems": [
          {
            "currentsubitemId": "789",
            "currentsubitemName": "NMPS",
            "CurrentStatus": "Present"
          },
          {
            "currentsubitemId": "873",
            "currentsubitemName": "NMSI",
            "CurrentStatus": "NotPresent"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]

Tried below jolt spec but it is not removing the
duplicate entry inside subitems array with status value update from
P to Present and
N to NotPresent
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "comp_id": "=concat(@(1,itemid),'_', @(1,itemName), '_', @(1,itemType))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,comp_id).&[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&",
        "comp_id": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "itemid": "=firstElement(@(1,itemid))",
        "itemName": "=firstElement(@(1,itemName))",
        "itemType": "=firstElement(@(1,itemType))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "itemid": "[&1].work_item.itemid",
        "itemName": "[&1].work_item.itemName",
        "itemType": "[&1].work_item.itemType",
        "subitemId": {
          "*": "[&2].work_item.wf_instance.subitems[&].currentsubitemId"
        },
        "subitemName": {
          "*": "[&2].work_item.wf_instance.subitems[&].currentsubitemName"
        },
        "Status": {
          "*": "[&2].work_item.wf_instance.subitems[&].CurrentStatus"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


You could group by itemid and subitemId by prefixing the right hand sides of the pairs by them such as
[
  {//grouping occurs here while Status literals are chenged conditionally 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "item*": "@1,itemid.&",
        "sub*": "@1,itemid.subitems.@1,subitemId.current&",
        "Status": {
          "P": {
            "#Present": "@3,itemid.subitems.@3,subitemId.Current&2"
          },
          "N": {
            "#NotPresent": "@3,itemid.subitems.@3,subitemId.Current&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of repetitions, eg. convert arrays to attributes 
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE",
        "subitems": {
          "*": {
            "*": "ONE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].work_item.&",
        "subitems": {
          "*": "[#3].work_item.wf_instance.&1[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


is it possible to updated the jolt spec i shared on top by adding few operation  just to remove the duplicate and keep the rest same ?

Done. when you get time please add the duplicate removal logic to the jolt spec i shared on top i have made all the changes similar to input but having lot child element need help to remove the duplicate inside the array object. thanks in advance

Hi @Barbaros Özhan  could you please check below query it looks similar to solution you suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78899638/jolt-spec-for-grouping-by-id-and-removing-the-duplicates-entry-inside-the-couple
